# Pylint throws E1120 error in dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, pylint

I've implemented a custom decorator which injects arguments to a function when necessary. Code works as expected, but pylint throws a E1120 error because it expects the injected instance as an argument.

```py
from injector import inject as inject_, Injector
import functools

def inject(func):
    func = inject_(func)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def execute(*args, **kwargs):
        injector = Injector([])
        self_, *args = args
        return injector.call_with_injection(func, self_=self_, args=tuple(args), kwargs=kwargs)

    return execute

class Util:
    @inject
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    
class ErrorResponse:
    @inject
    def __init__(self, email, util:  Util):
        self.email = email
        self.util = util

    def build_response(self):
        print(f"Error for email {self.email}")
        pass
    
def main():
    error_response = ErrorResponse('email') // No value for argument 'util' in constructor callPylintE1120:no-value-for-parameter

    error_response.build_response()
```

Is there a way to detect injected arguments? Am I implementing an anti-pattern? Is my only option to declare the problematic argument as optional?